# Detect all incoming HTTP files Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using a Google Chrome Extension, I would like to fire some event or somehow detect every HTTP response I receive in my browser.

Pretty much - I want to detect exactly what the "Network" tab of the Chrome developer tools sees using a Google Chrome Extension.

For example, if I open the Network tab and go to Google.com I see every .js, .css, image, etc.  Can I somehow detect that?

**Edit:**

I have tried the following (which I would expect to get fired after each request completes):

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) { alert('hey'); });
```

But that never seems to get fired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Web Request api for that, be aware that this came in at Chrome version 17 so youll have to set the `minimum_chrome_version` to 17.
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#minimum_chrome_version

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "WebRequest",
  "description": "WebRequest - onCompleted",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "webRequest"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    console.debug(details);
}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
});
```

Go to the background page and look in the console when a page is loading/loaded.

Comment: I tried that, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I added the following: chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) { alert('hey'); }); but I never get an alert.

Comment: @MattW You have to have a RequestFilter, its not optional... try it like this `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) { alert('hey'); },{urls:["<all_urls>"]});`

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example? I'm trying to do the same thing, but I just can't figure out how to run this successfully in a background task.

Comment: @sredmond Yep, I can do that for you ;)

Comment: Wow. This is why I love StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener
(
    TrackRequest,
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["responseHeaders"]
);


function TrackRequest(info)
{
        console.log(info);
}
```

and the manifest.js:

```
{
"name": "Ext",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Ext template",
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource://readme.js; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": ["webRequest","*://*/"]
}
```

You cannot make an "allert" from background script.
For debugging, go to extensions and click on "background page". You will see there the console output.